# Cookie Consent affects PageSpeed Insights score

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my website I am using Cookie Consent by insights: https://cookieconsent.insites.com/documentation/javascript-api/

When I load its javascript source, my google PageSpeed insight scores drops by a large number. The main analytic factor is "Prioritize Visible Content". When I include the script of cookie consent Only about 60% of the final above-the-fold content could be rendered with the full HTML response.

I have been doing trials by including this script after webpage is completely loaded (using bind, onload, ready, async, getScript, timeout) but it still affects my visible content.

Answer (score 1):

**First of all** you did not ask a question.

**Secondly**, it is better to do the cookie consent by your own because than you can optimize it the way you want.and it is not really complicated functionality.

The easiest way to do the cookie consent is to add a `div` only if cookie (for example `cookiebar`) is not set. If it is do not add it at all. Than it will affect your page only before someone will hide it. Than if you click a button to hide the bar just set cookie (`cookiebar`) and problem solved. It does not slows your page and works the way you want.